# Getting Error "Your project must have an Android package set in app.json" despite that fact that I have an android package set in app.json

Tags: windows, react-native, expo

I'm building a react native project using expo.  I'm on windows, so I enable WSL and install ubuntu from the microsoft store.  Next I run expo build:android.  I get the following error,

`Your project must have an Android package set in app.json.`

So I looked at expos tutorial page and it says to add,

```
"android": {
    "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname"
}
```

I add that to the `app.json` file and I get the same error.  I don't have the slightest idea as to why the error wont go away, because I've looked at the tutorial page and at my code, and I clearly have all the required fields.

This is the tutorial page I've been looking at : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/

Anyways, this is my app.json file,

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "First React App",
    "slug": "FirstReactNativeApp",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
      "supportsTablet": true,
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
  }
}
```

Comment: Btw, plz don't flame me for asking this; I'm aware that I'm bad at articulating questions

Comment: hello jak, welcome to stackoverflow! this looks like it should work as expected. my only guess is that you are running `expo build:android` from the incorrect directory. I copied and pasted your exact `app.json` from above into a new blank project and ran `expo build:android` and it worked on the first try without any modifications necessary. you can clone it and verify yourself if you like: https://github.com/brentvatne/stackoverflow-question-58359479

Comment: I fixed it. I never figured out why it wasn't working though. Anyways I fixed it by creating a new project, copying over all the code and building that. That ended up working. Anyways thanks for the help

Comment: For those who are getting in the same error in the latest projects, the fix for me was that I added  the below line in app.json                                                                                         "android": {
  "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
  "versionCode": 1
}                                                                                                                      moreover, also ran "yarn install" should also work "npx install" before running "npx start" or "yarn expo start"

Answer (score 20):

For anyone coming to this page, add the following to your app.json.

```
"android": {
  "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
  "versionCode": 1
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I just arrived here after experiencing the same problem. Turns out my `app.config.js` wasn't passing on configuration from `app.json`.

I fixed it by changing:

```
export default {
  extra: {
    [...]
  },
};
```

to:

```
export default ({config}) => {
  return Object.assign(config,
    {
      extra: {
        [...]
      }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This Worked for me, you can try this

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "kd-guess-number",
    "slug": "kd-guess-number",
    "sdkVersion": "37.0.0",
    "privacy": "public",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "description": "",

    "android": {
      "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
      "versionCode": 1
    }

  }
}
```

You should add this at the end (See above my code for reference)

```
"android": {
      "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
      "versionCode": 1
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I might be late for the this, but I found the issue at least for myself was because the Expo create-react-native-app might build the app.json different from what it actually wanted (I might be wrong). I created a new expo app and compare the two. I found that the structure of the json changed and `android` should be nested inside `expo` like the following. BTW, this is my first answer in stackoverflow.

Correct:

```
{
 "expo": {
   "name": "youappname",
   "android": {
     "package": "com.web.app",
     "versionCode": 1
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had declared the "android" property at the top level within app.json. Rather, it should've been listed within the "expo" property as a sub-key. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

//you have to update it in /android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

after adding package name and versionCode in my app.json, I still got the same error

```
"android": {
  "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
  "versionCode": 1
}
```

**NOTE:** I use Expo-CLI so I don't know if this works with Native CLI

I was able to fix the issue at hand and even fixed the issue with emulator throwing **"pixel launcher keeps stopping"** error.

in terminal, navigate to your projects directory and run the following commands:

```
> C:\project_dir> npx expo install react-native@0.69.5 expo-dev-client@~1.3.0

> C:\project_dir> npx expo install expo-dev-client@~1.2.1
```

and then run the npm command to run the emulator

```
> C:\project_dir> npm run android
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the same slug value in the app name package:

```
slug: 'myslug',
android: { package: 'com.mydomain.myslug' }
```