# React native project creation: create-expo-app: How to specify package name?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and it is my first projet.
There is a command:

```
react-native init my-project --package-name=com.mycompagny
```

But it seems that everyone use now

```
npx create-expo-app my-project
```

How to set package-name with create-expo-app?
Which command better?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58359479/getting-error-your-project-must-have-an-android-package-set-in-app-json-despit - refer this.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the expo app, you may use [react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename) library to rename your package name or your bundle id

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
You need to modify app.json file after generation as follow:
https://pagepro.co/blog/publishing-expo-react-native-app-to-ios-and-android/